# Tweening effect on the child of a movieclip in Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, tween

i've got a movieclip with several movieclips inside. If i create a "tweening" effect on the big movieclip, it works. But if i double click on this big movieclip (that contains the others) and try to move one of these movieclips (the children) with the same tweening effect (the classic one, or the one for the movement) it just does nothing)

How would you make the "inner" movieclip move? (i tried to move the child without moving the parent)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object, convert it into a symbol, double click and animate it. Navigate back the original scene (scene 1) and tween.

Nested movie clips when played back are not animated from the traditional press enter from keyframe 1, you need to use (Ctrl+enter or cmd+enter)

Comment: thanks Hmm, here's what i do : create 3 movieclips, convert them into a symbol, double click, create another keyframe and place one of the 3 movieclips a bit more on the right. Then the tweening effect : nothing happens...

Comment: alright i don't know what happened, but it works now, i guess my software has some problem with Mac os Lion, ... it works fine anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your symbols are `movieclips` and not `graphics`. Graphics don't have a timeline, so they can't play animated content inside.

Apart from that, if you create a movieclip and place another movieclip inside of it, you can animate it with no problems. If this is not working, there're some possible causes: you have not published or tested the movie to see the animation (as Humm pointed), your symbol is a graphic, as I've mentioned, or there's an ActionScript on one or more frames, that control the flow of the animation, like `stop()`, `gotoAndStop()`, and so on.

Comment: alright i don't know what happened, but it works now, i guess my software has some problem with Mac os Lion, ... it works fine anyway, thanks!